# How to build a small libcurl library?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I want to build the libcurl with a minimal configuration in order to get a small binary library size as much as possible.

I want that my libcurl support only:

- http
- https
- digest authentication
- basic authentication
- cookies
- http redirect

What is the best confuguration to get the smallest libcurl binary size?

I tried the following configuration:

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static \
--disable-dependency-tracking --enable-ipv6 --disable-ftp --disable-file \
--disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --disable-rtsp --disable-proxy --disable-dict \
--disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp \
--disable-gopher --disable-sspi --disable-manual --disable-zlib --without-zlib
```

and I got a libcurl.a with a size of 300k.

Is it possible to make it more smallest?

Comment: Did you strip debug symbols? thats a very large archive file.

Comment: @iharob `--disable-debug` ?

Comment: True, still, you can try `strip -s libcurl.a`

Comment: Prefix your configure line with `CFLAGS="-Os"` and run `strip(1)` on the generated `libcurl.a` as iharob suggests.

Comment: @iharob I m cross compiling with `cc=arm-linux-xxxx`. Does the strip work with the generated cross compiled lib ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there is no reason for it not to work, besides ther has to be a specific `arm-linux-strip` otherwise.

Comment: If you can't `strip`, ensure `CFLAGS` does not end up with `-g` in.

Comment: remember to build against an SSL library with a small footprint

Comment: what's the point to strip shared library? Just pass proper arguments when using libcurl.a when linking final executable.